# DesktopDuplicatipn API windows8 does not capture fullscreen games

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, directx, msdn

I was experimenting with desktopduplication api [sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a) and it was mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that

> even full screen DirectX applications can be duplicated.

Also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is mentioned that

> The following components of the operating system can generate the desktop image:
>
> - The DWM by composing the desktop image
> - A full-screen DirectX or OpenGL application
> - An application by switching to a separate desktop, for example, the secure desktop that is used to display the login screen

However when I tested the sample code with multiple monitors provided [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a), it worked fine for other applications running on desktop but when I started a fullscreen directx application, the running applications in the background are pushed onto the secondary monitor and only the secondary monitor is captured in the duplicated window.

What might be the reason for this? I ran the exact sample code provided by MSDN. Is there something more I need to do in order to capture DirectX fullscreen games using DesktopDuplication API

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in the question**. I also don't understand, why you added a [tag:c++-cli] tag. The sample code is written in C++.

Comment: I am simply running the entire solution provided by MSDN at the link of the sample code. I am not sure how to create an MCVE for this particular code since I have not written any part of it and also the problem I am facing requires the entire sample code of desktop duplication to run right. For testing you can simply download the project provided [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a) and debug it using Visual Studio 2013+. And @IInspectable sorry for the wrong tag. Will edit it right away.

Comment: Also ran sample project, it doesn't seem to capture full screen Direct X video games (Starcraft II) out of the box.